# .NET CLR not following codebase hints for binding a reference

Tags: c#, .net, reference, clr, .net-assembly

I'm trying to figure out why the `<codebase>` elements in my app.config file arent being looked at:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft.com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="SampleLibrary" publicKeyToken="d7c190e16be0999a" culture="neutral" />
        <codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="http://deployment/1.0.0.0/SampleLibrary.dll" /> 
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

The reference is strongly named, and the reference Copy Local=False. When i look at FUSLOGVW, it doesnt show that the codebase option was found in the app.config:

```
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\build\SampleProgram.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: SampleLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d7c190e16be0999a
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/source/repos/ConsoleApp1/build/SampleLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/source/repos/ConsoleApp1/build/SampleLibrary/SampleLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/source/repos/ConsoleApp1/build/SampleLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/source/repos/ConsoleApp1/build/SampleLibrary/SampleLibrary.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

How can i redirect the reference to the path in the codebase href element? It doesnt work with file:// paths either.